# DataExchange for many variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, variables, mfc

I'm new to MFC and creating basically a "preferences" tool. This of course means that there is a lot of input from the user. I have several "pages", each filled with a combination of text boxes and combo boxes, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to execute the DoDataExchange methods for each dialog class.

Of course, I could just go one by one, within each class for the different dialogs, but there must be a better/faster way. I really don't want to have to write hundreds upon hundreds of DDX_... lines to set up my variables.

Any ideas? I could class them out and then just use a for-loop to pull the variables from an array or list, but I'm not sure how to do that with CWnd and stuff.

Comment: Visual Studio 5, so Visual C++ using MFC.

Comment: No I was asking if you were using Visual Studio (if so what version) or a standard text editor etc.  We have legacy apps here that we build with visual studio 6.0 and all those type of statements are generated automatically whenever you build the gui and assign variables to the controls via the Class Wizard.

Comment: Maybe I didn't do it correctly when I was designing my dialogs...I have about 15 different dialogs that are invoked through a tree list, and each dialog has anywhere between 10 and 40 different text boxes/combo boxes. I wanted to figure out an easy way to initialize the dataexchanges for each dialog, maybe by looping through the IDs in the Resources.h file?

If I did something like this, it would be best because then I could use the same sort of thing to auto-clear everything, etc.

Comment: And sorry, I mean Visual Studio 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the wizard, it will automatically map the variable name to the dialog: right click on the dialog and Add variable, no need to write them manually.